# ON Semiconductor diode - markings 751 KE

Tags: diodes, identification

I can't seem to find this on the ON Semiconductor page. It's 4mm in length and about 3.5mm in width. Can you tell me how you figure it out, so I can learn?

[image: photo of component]

Comment: RV1 would indicate it being a varistor, not a diode.

Comment: I couldn't find any Varistors by ON Semi so I figured maybe it was a diode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be Transient Voltage Suppressors (transil) with **KE** markings:
**1SMB5.0AT3**

http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/1/s/1smbxxat3_on.pdf

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.